# Map observableArray containing an observable to a flat array

Tags: knockout.js

Can anybody show me how to map `self.fThings` to a flat array containing `Name` using `ko.util` functions?

```
function FItem(name) {
    var self = this;
    self.Name = ko.observable(name);
}

self.fThings = ko.observableArray([new FItem("Raindrops on roses"),
                                   new FItem("Whiskers on kittens"),
                                   new FItem("Bright copper kettles"),
                                   new FItem("Warm woolen mittens"),
                                   new FItem("Brown paper packages")]);
```

I've attempted this with both `arrayForEach` and `arrayMap` without success. I think because the `observable` contained in the `observableArray` complicates the operation. I've considered it might be bad practice to contain an `observable` in an `observableArray` (is it?), however changing to a static value breaks another part of the application.

Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to use `arrayForEach` (or a `for` loop for that matter) to achieve this:

```
self.plainThings = ko.computed(function() {
    var ret = [];
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.fThings(), function(item) {
        ret.push(item.Name());
    });
    return ret;
});
```

You could do this in a normal function or just call it as needed, but the benefit of doing it inside a `computed` is that if another item is added to (or one removed from) the `observableArray`, or one of the `Name` values change, anything that's bound to the plain array returned from the `plainThings` computed would also get updated.  [Demo fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ptxj361v/).

Or as you say, you can also do this with `arrayMap`.  That could look like this:

```
self.plainThings = ko.computed(function() {
    return ko.utils.arrayMap(self.fThings(), function(item) {
        return item.Name();
    });
});
```

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fyr82zd5/1/).  Or if you don't need it in a computed, just use the inner section directly:

```
var plainArray = ko.utils.arrayMap(self.fThings(), function(item) {
    return item.Name();
});
```

I wouldn't worry about putting `observable`s inside `observableArray`s etc - I've worked on viewmodels where things can be nested quite deeply, and thanks to knockout's chaining, when something updates, it all bubbles through nicely.

Comment: Thanks for your answer James. It wasn't working but I've found it does if I unwrap the observable.                              return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(item.Name);

Comment: @user1405195 It should have worked - it does in the fiddle.  Did you try it somewhere where you'd removed the `observable` from `.Name`, since you said you were unsure whether nesting `observable`s was a good idea?  You certainly can use `unwrapObservable`, though personally I'd only use it in situations where you don't know if `item.Name` is an `observable` or not.  If you know it's an `observable`, I'd just treat it as such and call the function directly.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for your help. It's now working as per your answer.